# How to display the top largest files in the format below using bash

Tags: bash, shell

```
-bash-4.1$ ./folder-stats-2.sh 
Top 5 files:
    ./index.html                 4000 bytes
    ./CS133/lab1.html            3245 bytes
    ./CS118/CW1/Ex1.java         2512 bytes
    ./CS118/CW2/GrandFinale.java  204 bytes
    ./.bashrc                      20 bytes
```

I am writing a bash script and I'm wondering how I can find the top 5 largest files when the script is ran in the current directory. Thanks in advance.

Edit: Its an assignment and the use of du, locate, find and any recursive commands to achive the task is not allowed

Comment: Try using `du` with `sort` and head/tail. Then, for formatting, you can use awk

Comment: Its an assignment and the use of du, locate, find and any recursive commands to achive the task is not allowed.

Comment: Then you should edit your question! Also, add what you have tried so far.

Comment: `Its for an assignment` yet no attempt has been made by OP at all

Comment: There was an attempt I made and it was almost perfect, TOP=$(ls -ls -a -S -h -p | head -6 | awk '{$6, $10}')

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this `stat`, `sort`, `awk` combination:

```
stat -c "%n:%F:%s" * | sort -t: -rnk3,3 | awk -F: '$2=="regular file"{
    printf "%25s\t%s bytes\n", $1, $3} NR>5{exit}'
                  foo.txt   639 bytes
                   bar.sh   453 bytes
              myscript.sh   383 bytes
                   baz.pl   330 bytes
                 proc.sql   328 bytes
```

- `stat -c "%n:%F:%s"` prints all file names, file type and file sizes
- `sort -t: -rnk3,3` is used for reverse numerical sorting on column # 3 (size)
- `awk` command searches for all lines with condition `$2=="regular file"` (to print only regular files) and prints formatted output using `printf`. `NR>5{exit}` exits `awk` process once we've printed 5 lines.

Comment: this solution does look nice and does seem to do the trick. Could you explain how it works it looks slightly complex. An explanation like the one below would be much appriciated. However if you don't have any time it is no problem. Thank you,

Comment: I can't make this produce same result as the example output

Comment: @Jasen: It worked for OP and me. Do you mean this `Top 5 files:` heading?

Comment: The OP is satisfied, which is fine by me if he want's to cheat on his assignment, google will show his instructor where he got his code from,   what I mean is the example found files in subdirectories.

Answer (score 2):

```
du -ab |sort -nr|head -6
```

in above line:

```
du 

-a : all files
-b : use byte as unit

sort

-n : sort as number
-r : reversely

head -6 : we take the first 6 lines, 
          because the 1st line output by `du` 
          is the total size of your directory..
```

The output format is like:

```
777777  .
77777   ./foo/bar
7777    ./foo/bar/a.big
777     ./foo/bar/b.big
77      ./foo/bar/blah/bigfile
7       ./other/dir/file
```

Comment: Whilst this answer is perfect I can't use it, I can't use du or any recursive commands. I need another way.

Answer (score 0):

As it's an assignemnt I'll get you started only.
you probably want to start with

```
for x in * .*
```

and then in the loop check if "$x" is is a file , directory  or symlink

- `.` and `..` you'll want to ignore
- symlinks, I guess, you ignore too
- files you check the size of and if in the top 5 remember them
- directories you recurse into.

when the loop ends, print the results.